# Using Ctrl+C multiple times in C

Tags: c

I'm currently trying to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to terminate individual `while` loops. However when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it is currently terminating both `while` loops. Is there a way I can make these individual?

This is how I currently have it setup:

```
volatile sig_atomic_t exitSig = 0;
volatile sig_atomic_t feedExitSig = 0;

void signal_handler(int signum){
    exitSig = 1;
    livefeedExitSig =1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    while (!exitSig){
         //complete task

         while (!feedExitSig){
               //complete task
         }

         //complete task
    }
}
```

If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> while I'm in the `feedExitSig` loop I want it to only exit that loop and not the `exitSig` loop.

Comment: `Ctrl + C` terminates your code, not one loop. You will need to use some other strategy, try to introduce one Keyboard combination capture in the loop in order to  terminate it.

Comment: Why not `if (livefeedExitSig) exitSig = 1;` in your signal handler to only set `exitSig` on the second `ctrl+c` interrupt? (in addition to setting `signal`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the correct catch by [@lenik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1329296/lenik) that `signal` is not called registering your `signal_handler()` function, you need to only set `exitSig` if `feedExitSig` is already set. You can do that with a simple conditional in your `signal_handler()`, e.g.

```
void signal_handler(int signum)
{
    if (signum == SIGINT) {
        if (feedExitSig)        /* only if feedExitSig already set */
            exitSig = 1;        /* set exitSig - requires 2nd ctrl+c */
        feedExitSig = 1;
    }
}
```

A complete example requiring Ctrl+c to be pressed to break the inner loop and then pressed again to break the outer loop ending the program could be similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t exitSig = 0;
volatile sig_atomic_t feedExitSig = 0;

void signal_handler(int signum)
{
    if (signum == SIGINT) {
        if (feedExitSig)        /* only if feedExitSig already set */
            exitSig = 1;        /* set exitSig - requires 2nd ctrl+c */
        feedExitSig = 1;
    }
}

int main (void) {

    signal (SIGINT, signal_handler);

    while (!exitSig){
        puts ("outer");

        while (!feedExitSig){
            puts ("  inner");
            sleep(1);
        }

        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Really appreciate your help! This is exactly what  I needed. Thank you so much!! :)

Comment: More than happy to help. Haven't waded into signals as a while so it was good for us both.

Answer (score 2):

In your `main()` you have to use `signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);` to let the system know you're about to handle `Ctrl/C` presses.

Once that done, you may want to set only one variable in the handler, not both, because right now you're terminating both loops at the same time.